# Good prior for correlated normal distributions

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, bayesian

I’m considering the following model:
$$
H \sim \pi(H) \\
{\theta_n} | H \sim N\left(0_n,
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1/H & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & 1/H & \cdots & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1/H
\end{array}\right)\right)
,
$$
where $\theta_n$ is an $n$-dimensional random vector.

I’m assuming that $H\in(0,1)$.
I’m wondering if there is a good prior $\pi$ for $H$.

I know that one can apply inverse gamma distribution for i.i.d. cases and inverse Wishart distribution for general multivariate cases.
But in this case, I can’t find any good material which refers this issue.

Does anyone have a nice idea? I’m basically interesting in its posterior mean, so even if you can’t find the posterior distribution, that’s fine.

Answer (score 0):

A [beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) distribution is a "typical" prior for parameter in $(0, 1)$. A special case is the uniform distribution on the range [0, 1].